# Flex container not wrapping items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I was creating a simple flexbox pricing page for my assignment and I ended up completing it. The problem is that the pricing cards do not wrap to the next row when the screen size is reduced i have set flex-wrap to wrap but still no luck. I searched this problem up and some results said that setting flex-container max-width to 100% would help, but it didn't. I have tried a bunch of other things but to no avail. Can someone help me with this?

CODE

```css
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
    color:  #00255A;
}



.card-container{
    display: flex;

    height: 80%;

    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}



.card{
    background-color: white;
    width:25%;
    height: 70%;
    border-radius: 5%;
    transition: .5s ease;
    border: 3px solid #00255A;
    overflow: hidden;
    
}

.card-heading{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 3px dotted #00255A;
    margin: 10px;
}

.card-body{
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin: 2%;
}

.card-price{

    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: 10%;
   font-size: larger;
}


.card-features{
    margin-top: 4%;
}

ul{
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    
}

ul li{
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: light;
    
}

.btn-container{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;

}

.btn-container button{
    width:150px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 3px solid #00255A ;
    transition: .5s ease-out;
}


.recommended{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    width:150px;
    top: 5px;
    left:-18px;
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
    padding-left: 15px;
    

}

.recommended h4{
    font-weight: lighter;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
}



/* Hover Effects */


.btn-container button:hover{
    background-color: #00255A;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px lightgray;


}

.card:hover{
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px lightgray;
    transform: translateY(-5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">

    <!-- Student Plan Card -->
    <div class="card">

        <div class="card-heading">
            <h3>Student</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-price">
                <h1>19.99/mo</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="card-features">

                <ul>
                    <li>24/7 Live Support</li>
                    <li>15GB Cloud Storage</li>
                    <li>Upto 5 Users</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-container">
            <button>Buy Now!</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Team Plan Card -->

    <div class="card" style="height: 80%; position: relative;">
        <div class="recommended">
            <h4>Popular</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-heading">
            <h3>Team</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-price">
                <h1>24.99/mo</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="card-features">

                <ul>
                    <li>24/7 Live Support</li>
                    <li>40GB Cloud Storage</li>
                    <li>Upto 10 Users</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-container">
            <button>Buy Now!</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Business Plan Card -->

    <div class="card" >
        <div class="card-heading">
            <h3>Business </h3>

        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="card-price">
                <h1>39.99/mo</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="card-features">

                <ul>
                    <li>24/7 Live Support</li>
                    <li>100GB Cloud Storage</li>
                    <li>Unlimited Users</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-container">
            <button>Buy Now!</button>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>
```

Comment: There is not any media query or fix width, so it wont wrap as your cards will be always `width:25%`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are my flex items not wrapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44742039/why-are-my-flex-items-not-wrapping)

Answer (score 1):

You have to strictly define the width of the cards. 25% is a relative value, meaning it will shrink to the proper size to fit the container. I added some margins for aesthetic reasons, and added a `flex: 1 0 0` - it grows if necessary, doesn't shink (if it does it won't wrap), and each card grows from the basis width defined in `width`. If you don't want it to grow, just define `flex:0 0 auto`, or just remove the `flex` line entirely, and define `justify-content: space-evenly`.

Note that you can hardcode it using media queries as well. In fact, I would recommend that as having different widths for your cards might be troublesome, and creating a pallette of cards of fixed widths would probably be easier.

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
  color: #00255A;
}

.card-container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  height: 80%;
  justify-content: stretch;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  background-color: white;
  width: 250px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  margin: 0 50px 20px 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  height: 70%;
  border-radius: 5%;
  transition: .5s ease;
  border: 3px solid #00255A;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card-heading {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 3px dotted #00255A;
  margin: 10px;
}

.card-body {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin: 2%;
}

.card-price {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10%;
  font-size: larger;
}

.card-features {
  margin-top: 4%;
}

ul {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: small;
  font-weight: light;
}

.btn-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.btn-container button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #00255A;
  transition: .5s ease-out;
}

.recommended {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
  top: 5px;
  left: -18px;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.recommended h4 {
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
}


/* Hover Effects */

.btn-container button:hover {
  background-color: #00255A;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px lightgray;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px lightgray;
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">

  <!-- Student Plan Card -->
  <div class="card">

    <div class="card-heading">
      <h3>Student</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-price">
        <h1>19.99/mo</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="card-features">

        <ul>
          <li>24/7 Live Support</li>
          <li>15GB Cloud Storage</li>
          <li>Upto 5 Users</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-container">
      <button>Buy Now!</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Team Plan Card -->

  <div class="card" style="height: 80%; position: relative;">
    <div class="recommended">
      <h4>Popular</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-heading">
      <h3>Team</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-price">
        <h1>24.99/mo</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="card-features">

        <ul>
          <li>24/7 Live Support</li>
          <li>40GB Cloud Storage</li>
          <li>Upto 10 Users</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-container">
      <button>Buy Now!</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Business Plan Card -->

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-heading">
      <h3>Business </h3>

    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-price">
        <h1>39.99/mo</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="card-features">

        <ul>
          <li>24/7 Live Support</li>
          <li>100GB Cloud Storage</li>
          <li>Unlimited Users</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-container">
      <button>Buy Now!</button>
    </div>
  </div>



</div>
```

You can view it in full screen and resize the browser to see how the wrapping works.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the with of the card to 25%. You'll need to add a media query (https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/CSS/Media_Queries) so you can set another with when the screen is too small.

```
.card{
    width: 50%;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px){
  .card{
    width: 30%
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use hard code for `width` to wrap else you can use `@media` for different screen sizes if you want to use soft code .

> Add margin and padding according to need

`@media` like this :

```
@media (max-width: 776px){
  .card {
    width: 48%;
    margin: 2% 1%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 500px){
  .card {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 2% auto;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Poppins, sans-serif;
  color: #00255A;
}

.card-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 80%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
  background-color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 70%;
  margin: 5px;  /*Add according to need*/
  border-radius: 5%;
  transition: .5s ease;
  border: 3px solid #00255A;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card-heading {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 3px dotted #00255A;
  margin: 10px;
}

.card-body {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin: 2%;
}

.card-price {
  width: 60%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10%;
  font-size: larger;
}

.card-features {
  margin-top: 4%;
}

ul {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: small;
  font-weight: light;
}

.btn-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.btn-container button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #00255A;
  transition: .5s ease-out;
}

.recommended {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 150px;
  top: 5px;
  left: -18px;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.recommended h4 {
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
}


/* Hover Effects */

.btn-container button:hover {
  background-color: #00255A;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px lightgray;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px lightgray;
  transform: translateY(-5px);
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">

  <!-- Student Plan Card -->
  <div class="card">

    <div class="card-heading">
      <h3>Student</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-price">
        <h1>19.99/mo</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="card-features">

        <ul>
          <li>24/7 Live Support</li>
          <li>15GB Cloud Storage</li>
          <li>Upto 5 Users</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-container">
      <button>Buy Now!</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Team Plan Card -->

  <div class="card" style="height: 80%; position: relative;">
    <div class="recommended">
      <h4>Popular</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-heading">
      <h3>Team</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-price">
        <h1>24.99/mo</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="card-features">

        <ul>
          <li>24/7 Live Support</li>
          <li>40GB Cloud Storage</li>
          <li>Upto 10 Users</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-container">
      <button>Buy Now!</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Business Plan Card -->

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-heading">
      <h3>Business </h3>

    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="card-price">
        <h1>39.99/mo</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="card-features">

        <ul>
          <li>24/7 Live Support</li>
          <li>100GB Cloud Storage</li>
          <li>Unlimited Users</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-container">
      <button>Buy Now!</button>
    </div>
  </div>



</div>
```